# How to extract report from jmeter in gui mode

Tags: jmeter

I have created script using jmeter and ran it,I then save the file as .jmx
but after closing and reopen the jmeter,I am not able to extract that .jmx file that i have created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using some listener to have the results:
- View Results Tree component
- Aggregate Report
....

In order to save those data, you need to fill in the **Filename** field and select which fields you want to save using **Configure** button.

This will save results to XML or CSV depending on the configuration you select,  you can then reload these files in JMeter when you open again you JMX, by putting mouse in **Filename** field and using **Enter** Key.